# Copy string from BSS variable to BSS variable in Assembly

Tags: string, assembly, copy, nasm

Let's suppose I have to string stored in variables created in the .BSS section.

```
var1    resw    5 ; this is "abcde" (UNICODE)
var2    resw    5 ; here I will copy the first one
```

How would I do this with NASM?
I tried something like this:

```
mov ebx, var2 ; Here we will copy the string
mov dx, 5 ; Length of the string
mov esi, dword var1 ; The variable to be copied
.Copy:
    lodsw
    mov [ebx], word ax ; Copy the character into the address from EBX
    inc ebx ; Increment the EBX register for the next character to copy
    dec dx ; Decrement DX
    cmp dx, 0 ; If DX is 0 we reached the end
    jg .Copy ; Otherwise copy the next one
```

So, first problem is that the string is not copied as UNICODE but as ASCII and I don't know why. Secondly, I know there might be some not recommended use of some registers. And lastly, I wonder if there is some quicker way of doing this (maybe there are instructions specially created for this kind of operations with strings). I'm talking about 8086 processors.

Comment: `inc`/`dec`/`cmp`? Why not `rep stos`?

Comment: Because I didn't know it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`inc ebx ; Increment the EBX register for the next character to copy`

A word is 2 bytes, but you're only stepping `ebx` 1 byte ahead. Replace `inc ebx` with `add ebx,2`.

Answer (score 1):

Michael already answered about the obvious problem of the demonstrated code.

But there is also another layer of understanding. It is not important how you will copy the string from one buffer to another - by bytes, words or double words. It will always create exact copy of the string.

So, how to copy the string is a matter of optimization. Using **rep movsd** is the fastest known way.

Here is one example:

```
; ecx contains the length of the string in bytes
; esi - the address of the source, aligned on dword
; edi - the address of the destination aligned on dword
    push ecx
    shr  ecx, 2
    rep movsd
    pop  ecx
    and  ecx, 3
    rep movsb
```